# Second moment method in probability

Tags: probability, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am doing some probability work with "bounds". An example is given for something called the *second moment method*. The example proceeds as follows:

> $$X = I_1 + \dots + I_n,$$
>
> where the $I_j$ are uncorrelated indicator r.v.s. Let $p_j = E(I_j)$. Then
>
> $$\text{Var}(X) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \text{Var}(I_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^n (p_j - p_j^2) = \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j - \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j^2 = \mu - c,$$
>
> where $\mu = E(X), c = \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j^2$. Also, $E(X^2) = \text{Var}(X) + (EX)^2 = \mu^2 + \mu - c$. So
>
> $$P(X = 0) \le \dfrac{\text{Var}(X)}{E(X^2)} = \dfrac{\mu - c}{\mu^2 + \mu - c} \le \dfrac{1}{\mu + 1},$$
>
> where the last inequality is easily checked by cross-multiplying.

I don't understand why $\dfrac{\mu - c}{\mu^2 + \mu - c} \le \dfrac{1}{\mu + 1}$ is true. I began by seeing if I could simplify $\dfrac{\mu - c}{\mu^2 + \mu - c}$ by factoring out the numerator $\mu - c$ from the denominator $\mu^2 + \mu - c$. Using polynomial division, I got that $\mu^2 + \mu - c = (\mu - c)(\mu(1 + c)) + c^2$, so that didn't work out. Would anyone please explain to me why $\dfrac{\mu - c}{\mu^2 + \mu - c} \le \dfrac{1}{\mu + 1}$ is true? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what you have quoted, "the last inequality is easily checked by cross-multiplying"

Note that since $p_j \in (0, 1)$, $\displaystyle \mu = \sum_{j=1}^n p_j > 0 $ and thus $1 + \mu > 0$.

Also we have $p_j > p_j^2$, therefore $\displaystyle \mu - c 
=  \sum_{j=1}^n p_j - \sum_{j=1}^n p_j^2 \geq 0$ and thus $\mu^2 + \mu - c > 0$

With both denominator checked as positive, we can cross-multiply the inequality without changing the inequality sign:

$$ \begin{align}
\frac {\mu - c} {\mu^2 + \mu - c} & \leq \frac {1} {\mu + 1} \\
\iff (\mu - c)(\mu + 1) & \leq \mu^2 + \mu - c \\
\iff \mu^2 - \mu c + \mu - c & \leq \mu^2 + \mu - c \\ 
\iff -\mu c & \leq 0
\end{align} $$

So the inequality is always true as $\mu > 0, c > 0$